renaming files in folder from excel
i'm trying to rename files in a specific folder, using a list of new names in a column of an excel file.In the following code i've tried just with one file without loop. It returns 'runtime errore 53' - 'impossible to find the file'. What i found confusing is that in the error line 'name nome_vecchio as nome_nuovo' the pop up is giving me the right names.
Thank you in advance for your help.
'assegna valore indirizzo desktop
desktop_path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialFolders("Desktop")

'apri il file
Workbooks.Open (desktop_path & ("\fatture booking.xls"))

'trova ultima riga usata in c
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Row

nome_vecchio = Dir(desktop_path & "\fatture booking\*.pdf")
nome_nuovo = Cells(2, "c")
Name nome_vecchio As nome_nuovo

I've tried to rename files in a folder with a name written in a cell of a sheet.
In column C, starting from row 2 there are a list of names like '3T - affitti' which are the new names i want to use. At the moment i'm just trying with one name, later i will add the loop. I've changed the code this way, defining the path, but returns that the files already exists, but the file name hasn't changed.
'assegna valore indirizzo desktop
desktop_path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialFolders("Desktop")

'indirizzo cartella fatture booking
indirizzo_cartella = desktop_path & "\fatture booking\"

'apri il file
Workbooks.Open (desktop_path & ("\fatture booking.xls"))

'trova ultima riga usata in c
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Row

nome_vecchio = indirizzo_cartella & Dir(desktop_path & "\fatture booking\*.pdf")
nome_nuovo = Cells(2, "c")
MsgBox nome_nuovo
Name nome_vecchio As nome_nuovo

Thank you to everybody, i just needed to add the path as CLR told.
Name indirizzo_cartella & nome_vecchio As indirizzo_cartella & nome_nuovo


Dir returns just the filename of the pdf it finds - i.e. without the filepath. Name requires the full filepath.

What exactly is in column C? Share a few examples. Although the file names returned by Dir might seem sorted in a way, they might not be. The number of files may be different than the number of populated cells. Best use another column for the original names and rename using the corresponding values in each row.

Look at https://trumpexcel.com/vba-dir-function/ for a way to get the files in a folder one by one.
